# Property of children from lastSnapshot of an element in iOS UI Testing is always being empty, why?

Tags: ios, children, xcode-ui-testing

I'm studying the UI testing framework *WebDriverAgent* from facebook. It's very great and helpful. It almost contains all knowledge of iOS UI testing.

XCTest has many unpublic classes and properties. For example, XCUIElement has a property named lastSnapshot, and lastSnapshot also has many useful properties, like *label*, *identifier*, *frame*, *parent*, *children*, *pathDescription*, ect. Here's the question:

The *children* property is used to get all children elements from from certain element, just like the subviews from a view. But when I trying to get the value of *children* from lastSnapshot of an element, it is always being empty. While I can rightly get values of the other properties like label, identifier, parent, etc. This does troubled me for several days. Here's the exapmle code:

```
- (void)testExample {
    XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
    XCUIElement *windowElement = [app.windows elementBoundByIndex:2];
    XCUIElement *statusBarElement = [windowElement.query elementBoundByIndex:0];
    XCUIElement *otherElement = [statusBarElement.query elementBoundByIndex:1];
    XCUIElement *timeElement = [otherElement.query elementBoundByIndex:2];

    [timeElement query];
    [timeElement resolve];
    NSLog(@"lastSnapshot = %@", timeElement.lastSnapshot);
    NSLog(@"children = %@", timeElement.lastSnapshot.children);
}
```

Comment: Before studing WebDriverAgent, I used a category of XCUIElement to recursive the element tree:

Answer (score 0):

Before studing WebDriverAgent, I used a category of XCUIElement to recursive the element tree:

```
- (XCUIElementNode *)recursiveUIElementsWithLevel:(NSInteger)elementLevel {
    XCUIElementNode *node = [XCUIElementNode new];
    node.elementLevel = elementLevel;
    node.elementValue = self;
    NSArray *arrayNotIncludeSelf = [self recursiveUIElementsNotIncludeSelfWithLevel:elementLevel];
    node.subNodes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrayNotIncludeSelf];

    return node;
}

- (NSArray *)recursiveUIElementsNotIncludeSelfWithLevel:(NSInteger)elementLevel {
    NSMutableArray *elementArray = [NSMutableArray new];

    XCUIElementQuery *childrenQuery = [self childrenMatchingType:XCUIElementTypeAny];

    for (NSUInteger elementIndex = 0; elementIndex < childrenQuery.count; elementIndex ++) {
        XCUIElement *element = [childrenQuery elementBoundByIndex:elementIndex];
        XCUIElementNode *subNode = [XCUIElementNode new];
        subNode.elementLevel = elementLevel + 1;
        subNode.elementValue = element;
        subNode.subNodes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[element recursiveUIElementsNotIncludeSelfWithLevel:subNode.elementLevel]];
        [elementArray addObject:subNode];
    }

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:elementArray];
}
```

It doese work by this way, but the recursive traversal experience takes a lot of time that can't be accepted.

Comment: If you upgrade to Xcode 9 and the iOS 11 simulator, query time has been optimised so that snapshotting and repeated traversal is not so slow anymore.

Comment: I tried again after upgraded to Xcode 9 and the iOS 11 simulator, it's still very slow traversing the children elements by the class of childrenMatchingType: